# How do I specify the xi and yi inputs of the improfile function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, api, image-processing, input

[This](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/improfile.html) reference API article about `improfile` specifies a few different ways to call it. I am intersted in using the the function `improfile(I,xi,yi)`. The example on the same page specifies `xi` and `yi` as `1x4` vectors. On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123896/not-sure-where-my-code-is-going-wrong-when-using-improfile-in-matlab/35125866#35125866) question which I asked a few days ago, I was given similar sort of inputs for `xi` and `yi`.

The objective of my improfile call is to measure the intensity of the image through the very center (if the rectangle below was an image, the red line is where I want to measure the intensity profile).

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit vague can you clarify if you are trying to calculate the intensity of each image in the stack and compare it against the other stack or you are combining a stack of image using some function and calculating the intensity of the whole stack? the vectors x and y in improfile specifies the area in the image you wish to calculate intensity for.

Comment: @GameOfThrows I have added some clarification to the question

Comment: and you are asking how to specify the x and y coordinates to cover an area / line of pixels of the red line region?

Comment: @GameOfThrows yeah, I'm not sure as to how two equal line vectors make a single line vector when it comes to specifying `xi` and `yi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still trying to understand what you are trying to ask, but from my basic understanding, I think this might be what you are after:

```
A = rgb2gray(YourImage);; %//convert to Greyscale for simplicity
xi = [1 size(A,2) size(A,2) 1]; 
yi = [ceil(size(A,1)/2), ceil(size(A,1)/2), ceil(size(A,1)/2 ),ceil(size(A,1)/2)] %//These x and y coordinates is the red line which you drew with a width of 1 pixel.
```

The xi and yi are basically your 4 corner coordinates, if you only need 2 coordinate (i.e you only need a line), set the 4 y coordinates to the same (for a horizontal line), or set your 4 x coordinates to the same for a vertical line.

```
improfile(A,xi,yi),grid on;
```

[image: Result image]

as you can see, the intensity of the border (which is black) and the the contrast to the red line.

Comment: would you elaborate as to why you chose those specific values for `xi` and `yi`

Comment: Yeah that clears it, let me just try this and answer back whether or not it works. The API wasn't very clear about the selection of the coordinates for `xi` and `yi`.

Comment: well, it is a presumed knowledge, just like Matlab's matrix indexing (i.e. A(1,2) - A(row,column) ) The Matlab coordinate system is similar A(x,y) x is the horizontal measurement and y is the vertical measurement.

Comment: I still don't understand why 4 coordinates are needed, twice over in the form of `xi` and `yi`

Comment: 4 coordinates for a square area on your image, each coordinate must have a x and y reading (which corresponds to your 4 pairs of values in the x and y vectors) - also note that it does not have to be square, but any shape (made using coordinates).

Comment: And there we go! I finally understand the concept of `xi` and `yi`. Thanks a lot!